# Flutter StateNotifier, AsyncValue, StateNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning state management with flutter. I want to display error dialog when the error or exception is thrown by the API. Below is how I implemented the the provider state.

```
`// Creating state where the freezed annotation will suggest that boilerplate code needs to be generated
@Freezed()
abstract class TodoState with _$TodoState {
  const factory TodoState({@Default([]) List<TodoDTO> todos}) = _TodoState;

  const TodoState._();
}

// Creating state notifier provider
final todoStateProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<TodoNotifier, AsyncValue<TodoState>>(
        (ref) => TodoNotifier());

// Creating Notifier
class TodoNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<TodoState>> {
  final TodoService todoService = TodoServiceImpl();

  // Notifier constructor - call functions on provider initialization
  TodoNotifier() : super(AsyncValue.loading()) {
    loadTop40Todos();
  }

  // loadTodos top 40 todos
  void loadTop40Todos() async {
    state = AsyncValue.loading();
    final AsyncValue<List<TodoDTO>?> av =
        await AsyncValue.guard(() async => todoService.loadTopEntities());
    final List<TodoDTO> list = av.value!;
    state = AsyncValue.data(TodoState());
    state = AsyncValue.data(state.value!.copyWith(todos: list));
  }`
```

Secondly, this is how I implemented my ConsumerWidget

[image]

My code is not working, the error dialog doesn't show even when i purposefully throw an error from the API. I just see the loading screen forever. However, the error is only triggered when explicitly assign my state to error as shown below. My understanding is that the guard function call should take care of that? It's even written in the documentation, that it does error handling for you.
`state = AsyncError(error, stackTrace)` or `state = AsyncValue.error(error, stackTrace)`

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the issue, but decided to use something else

`
AsyncNotifierProvider<TodoNotifier, TodoState>(TodoNotifier.new);

```
// Creating Notifier
class TodoNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<TodoState> {
  final TodoService todoService = TodoServiceImpl();

  // loadTodos top 40 todos
  @override
  FutureOr<TodoState> build() async {
    state = AsyncValue.loading();
    final AsyncValue<List<TodoDTO>?> av =
        await AsyncValue.guard(() async => todoService.loadTopEntities());
    final List<TodoDTO> list = av.value!;
    state = AsyncValue.data(TodoState());
    return state.value!.copyWith(todos: list);
  }
```

`

This